# How do I deal with CORS problem for Angular app deployed on heroku with a Postgres express backend?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors

I am deploying my Angular app and a Postgres Express backend to heroku to allow them to talk with one another. The big problem that I have now is that whenever I try to use fetch methods, it says that I need CORS enabled or a heading for it. I already set it up in my express backend below:

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;
const transRoutes = require('./transactions');
const groupsRoutes = require('./budget-group');
const itemsRoutes = require('./budget_item');
const accRoutes = require('./account');

app.use(cors({origin: '*'})); //I also tried cors()
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/transactions', transRoutes);
app.use('/groups', groupsRoutes);
app.use('/items', itemsRoutes);
app.use('/accounts', accRoutes);
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
 })

const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to your server.');
});

app.get('/users', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const getAllUsers = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users");
        res.json(getAllUsers);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

app.get('/login/:username/:password', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const getUser = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1 AND password = $2",
        [
            req.params.username,
            req.params.password
        ]);
        res.json(getUser.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

//More routes omitted for brevity

app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)});
```

I think my code is fine for the backend, so I feel that the Angular code is the problem, but I don't understand how to fix it. Do I have to manually add a header for each fetch method done to have the CORS feature, or do I have to use some sort of proxy that I found but was too confused how to do it?

An example of a fetch method I did is below:

```
fetch(`https://name-redacted.herokuapp.com/login/${this.username}/${this.password}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
      }).then(res => res.json())
      .then(info => {
        if (info.length === 0) {
          this.failedAuth = true;
        } else {
          this.infoService.setUpLoginInfo(info[0]);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/instructions');
        }
      });
```

Also for deploying the angular part, I followed this guide:
https://youtu.be/KVFrTf4VD2o
I just thought it might be important since it uses an express server to give the files instead of doing ng serve after building the app.

Edit:
For the CORS error: Access to fetch at 'https://app-backend.herokuapp.com/register' from origin 'https://app-project.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods is not shown.

Comment: Just as a security concern, are you sure that passing your username and password in the URL is a good idea?

Comment: More in line with your question however, have you tried calling your endpoint with something like Postman or Insomnia to verify that your endpoint has those CORS headers actually set?

Comment: When I did it with postman just now, for the header, it showed: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'. Is there something else that should be shown?

Comment: What do the Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers look like? And also, what exactly does the CORS error say?

Comment: @witheroux I changed the post to show what you asked for.

Comment: CORS headers should be setup BEFORE your routes. (though that doesn't explain the cors error on login)

Comment: TLDR if the  browser says no access-control headers are present... no access-control headers are present. that would indicate that your middleware that sets them isn't being hit... usually it's an indicator that you have middleware and routes out of order, or that your logic for the  middleware is incorrect.

Comment: @KevinB So if I want to fix this, what is the middleware exactly? And also what should I look for when trying to fix it?

Comment: Make sure your `*` is not ignored. It would be ignored for any request with credentials. In this case you need an explicit domain value rather than just `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to solve my problem. @WiktorZychla's comment was correct in that any request with credentials will cause * to not work. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials)
To fix this, I found another discussion where they put:

```
const allowedOrigins = ['https://someapp.com'];
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
        callback(null, true) 
      } else {
        callback(new Error(`Origin: ${origin} is now allowed`))
      }
    }
  }));
```

You first create an allowedOrigins array to put any urls that you use to access the API. Then you let your server use a cors object that allows credentials and then checks the origin of the request. If the origin exists in the array, then it will return a callback that allows each request to work.

Also if you have separate routes like I do below:

```
const transRoutes = require('./transactions');
const groupsRoutes = require('./budget-group');
const itemsRoutes = require('./budget_item');
const accRoutes = require('./account');
app.use('/transactions', transRoutes);
app.use('/groups', groupsRoutes);
app.use('/items', itemsRoutes);
app.use('/accounts', accRoutes);
```

Then in each route file, you need to copy the cors info I have at the top and change it so that each router has cors configured. There may be another solution, but this was the fastest for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your server is just not ready to handle pre-flight requests. You don't seem to have any route that handles the OPTIONS HTTP method which a pre-flight request would be. Express' documentation on CORS has an example on [how to handle pre-flight requests](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

The simplest way to enable it on all requests, as per the documentation, would be to configure a route that handles OPTIONS as such:

```js
app.options('*', cors())
```